# Can I use Epson WF-2760 with Black ink only

Tags: epson-workforce

My color ink cartridges on my Epson WF-2760 are out. I don't want to ever print in color. But I can't seem to get the printer to work without the color cartridges. Is this possible? If so how do I do it?